# How to validate an email address in PHP against LDAP server?

Tags: php, validation, email, ldap

Back in the Classic ASP days, I had a nice little function that would allow you to take an email address, and check it against an LDAP server to make sure it was valid. (no username or password needed)

Can this be done in PHP?

I am NOT asking how to authenticate a username/password, or how to search LDAP.

I am NOT asking to validate the "format" of an email address.

I simply need to check LDAP to see if an email address is valid or not in Active Directory/LDAP - in other words, check to see if the email address "exists" in LDAP/Active Directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add sample code you have tried so far, learn to ask a good question on StackOverflow at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when you know how to search in LDAP then I don't understand the question. You have an email-address which should be the value of a mail-attribute in the LDAP. If a search doesn't return an entry the email-address seems not to exist. So what is the question?

Comment: Is the LDAP-server the right server to ask? Perhaps the SMTP would provide more information whether the address is "valid"?

Comment: I'm looking for the actual PHP code to validate an email address - sorry SsouLlesS, I thought the question was clear. All the sample code I found so far was how to "authenticate" with a known account and password - not what I need. Not sure how to ask any clearer: if I have someone enter myemail@mydomain.com in a textbox, I need to ensure that email exists in active directory/LDAP.